# How to compare datatype of column to a given datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a SQL change script that checks for a specific datatype of a column and edits the datatype if the column is of that type.

For example

```
IF (SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Xml') = 'xml')
```

I want the above code to return true if the 'Xml' column in 'Table' is of type Xml. I need to change it to `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Would it be safer if you do it this way?
Step 1: Find all columns with the desired data type
Step 2: Go through each column, and manually update the data type

Comment: I only need to change this one columns datatype not all of them that have xml datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such scripts I use [SQL Server metadata/catalog](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522(v=sql.105).aspx) views instead of views from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`:

**For untyped XML columns:**

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    sys.columns c
    JOIN    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    JOIN    sys.types tp ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    WHERE   s.name = N'dbo'
    AND     t.name = N'Table1'
    AND     c.name = N'Col2'
    AND     tp.name= N'xml'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
    ALTER COLUMN ...
END
```

**For typed XML columns:**

```
IF EXISTS(
    SELECT  xmlcol.*
    FROM    sys.columns c
    JOIN    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    JOIN    sys.xml_schema_collections xmlcol ON c.xml_collection_id = xmlcol.xml_collection_id
    JOIN    sys.schemas xmlcols ON xmlcol.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE   s.name = N'Production'
    AND     t.name = N'ProductModel'
    AND     c.name = N'Instructions'
    AND     xmlcols.name = N'Production'
    AND     xmlcol.name = N'ManuInstructionsSchemaCollection'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1
    ALTER COLUMN ...
END
```

Note: If I would convert XML values to text values I would use `NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Thanks! The two snippets are the same tho.